# Скрытие соседних элементов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, всех с Новым годом!)

Есть такой Html код:

```
<div>
<span id="a1b">Пункт 1</span>
<span id="a2b">Пункт 2</span>
<span id="a3b">Пункт 3</span>
<span id="a4b">Пункт 4</span>
<span id="a5b">Пункт 5</span>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при клике на `id="a3b"` скрывались все `span`, кроме того, на который нажали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать с [jQuery siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

```
$(function() {
    $('#a3b').on('click', function() {
        $(this)
            .siblings()
            .hide();
    });
});
```

**DEMO: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a06a0ku4/1/)**

Если нужно скрывать соседние элементы при клике на любой из `span`, то просто поменяйте селектор `$('#a3b')` на нужный.